# the method sort of class range failed c# - excel

Tags: c#, excel, sorting

I´m trying to sort a column using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel using c# and I'm getting a "the method sort of class range failed" error. The code are:

```
        Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("D:/rank.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 
        Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Sheets;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(2);

        Excel.Range oRng = worksheet.get_Range("E4", "E100");
        oRng.Activate();
        oRng.Cells.Select();

        oRng.Sort(Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Type.Missing,Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, 
        Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
        Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal);

        theWorkbook.Save();
        theWorkbook.Close();
        objApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objApp);
```

Am I missing something?

The spreadsheet are not protected and doesn't have a password to open it (I've tried in a simple spreadsheet with one column and 30 rows and doesn't work either)

If anyone can help, I'll be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neo

Answer (score 1):

```
oRng.Sort("This should be column name you going sort",
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
    Type.Missing,Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
    Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo,
    Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing,
    Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns,
    Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin, 
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal,
    Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Big ups man.
This was the assortment of parameters I needed.
One change that helped, the first parameter, instead of a literal string, I used the Excel.Range variable of the column I needed to sort by.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.  This will undoubtedly help anyone who is trying to sort a sheet using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a macros in Excel and then implement saved VB code in C#.

Comment: Hi Dmitry,Thanks for your answer.
But how exactly can I do that? I have to put vb code directly in c#, is that possible? Thanks

Comment: @v00d00 please answer lincoln's questions